# Flask.session cookies getting flagged as 3rd party?

Tags: python, flask, cookies, backend

I'm using [flask.session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.session) to store cookies, and it works fine.

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.get('/')
def index():
  flask.session['stuff'] = 0x012
  return flask.render_template('index.html')

app.get('/hello')
def hello():
  stuff = flask.session.get('stuff')  # Returns `None` when 3rd party cookies are disabled on Chrome/Chromium
  return flask.render_template('hello.html', stuff=stuff)
```

But on Chrome/Brave/Chromium it doesn't work when you disable 3rd party cookies, ie. `flask.session.get()` returns `None` for stuff you store in other routes/requests.

Why is that, and how can it be fixed (while allowing users to keep 3rd party cookies disabled)?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe elaborate a little more?

Comment: @KevinHernandez Sure! `flask.session.get()` returns `None` for stuff that you store in other routes/requests when 3rd party cookies are disabled on Chrome/Brave/Chromium. Let me know if you'd like more detail

Comment: Sessions in general rely on cookies. But you should check some Flask parameters in your application like `SERVER_NAME`, that determine the domain name for the cookies. Check the [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/)